# Traversing empty / undefined XML nodes in Javascript with IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, undefined, xmlnode

Same old story:  something works in Firefox / Chrome, but not in IE.

```
var reason = '';
if (data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("DNFReason")[0].childNodes[0] !== undefined)
{   reason = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("DNFReason")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue; }
```

This was the first workable solution I had found for getting the value of an XML node from an XML document in Javascript, so I'm bummed that it apparently won't work in IE.

It works fine if the node has a value, so the issue is clearly being caused by an empty / undefined node.

Anyone have any wisdom concerning this?  I was also looking for a slightly less verbose way of coding it (maybe in jQuery), but I was under a time constraint and didn't have the time to research like I needed to.

Full ajax request added:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "SheriffWS.asmx/GetGroupByID",
                data: 'GroupID=' + $("#<%=Groups.ClientID() %>").val(),
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(data) {
                    var gtype = '';
                    var reason = '';
                    var nme = '';
                    var ttype = '';
                    var ttypeid = 0;

                    if (data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Type")[0].childNodes[0] !== undefined) {
                        gtype = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Type")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    }

                    if (data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0] !== undefined) {
                        nme = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    }

                    if (data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("DNFReason")[0].childNodes[0] !== undefined) {
                        reason = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("DNFReason")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    }

                    if (data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("TestName")[0].childNodes[0] !== undefined) {
                        ttype = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("TestName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    }

                    if (data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("TestTypeID")[0].childNodes[0] !== undefined) {
                        ttypeid = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("TestTypeID")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    }

                    $("#groupinfo-name").val(nme);
                    $("#hid-name").val(nme);

                    $("#groupinfo-type").val(gtype);
                    $("#groupinfo-testtype").val(ttype);
                    $("#groupinfo-testtypeid").val(ttypeid);
                    if (data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("DNF")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue == 'false') {
                        $("#groupedit-dnf").removeAttr('checked');
                        $("#groupedit-dnf-li").hide();
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#groupedit-dnf").attr('checked', 'checked');
                        $("#groupedit-dnf-li").show();
                    }

                    $("#<%=GroupEditDNFReason.ClientID() %>").val(reason);
                    $("#hid-dnfreason").val(reason);
                },
                error: function(msg) {

                }

            });
```

Comment: What "doesn't work" in IE? Does it throw an error? Does it return an empty value? It would probably make sense to store the result of `data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("DNFReason")[0].childNodes[0]` in a variable instead of running it twice, too

Comment: It's throwing an error; oddly, it's throwing it in the jQuery 1.6.4 min file (the standard "object expected" error).  This is located in the success callback of an AJAX GET request, which is part of a Change event callback on a Select element.

I don't think this is the reason it's throwing the error; I just didn't want to complicate things.

Comment: You still didn't explain what's happening. If it's throwing an error in jQuery, that means it's not this code (you don't have any jQuery here). Since you're already using the jQuery for the AJAX, you might as well use it for traversing this XML. And I would definitely include your full `$.ajax()` call in your question...a lot of things may affect this

Comment: It's inside of an ajax request.  I've updated my question with the full code, although I've narrowed the source of the error down to the line of code I mentioned in my question, so I really don't think the extra code will help your cause any.  I've had plenty of times where an error was thrown from a jQuery script when the source of the error had nothing to do with jQuery, so I'm not sure where you're going with that.

I also stated that I was under a time constraint and did it the only way I knew how.  If I knew how to do it using jQuery, I would.

Comment: To use jQuery, make `data` a jQuery object first: `data = $(data);`. Then, to get the specific things you're looking for, try: `gtype = data.find("Type").first().children().first().text();`. Depending on your XML structure/content. No need to use the `if` statements, just set the variables. If the element isn't found, or if it doesn't have content, it will use an empty string. And obviously that can be applied to the rest of your variable setting.

Comment: Thanks; that did the trick and avoided the problem I ran into using Javascript alone